# How to limit input from user to numbers and letters only in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, inputstream

The program only needs *numbers and/or letters* as input from the user. otherwise, the program must be terminated. I don't know how to limit the input to numbers and letters only.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input, reversed = "";

    cout << "Enter string: "; 
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i < input.length(); i--)
    {
        reversed += input[i];
    }
    cout << reversed << endl;

    if (reversed == input)  cout << "It is a palindrome!"; 
    else            cout << "No, it is not a palindrome!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop will never end, because in `i < input.length()` your `i` will always be lesser than `input.length()`

Comment: I recommend you read about [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), about [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and about [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: take a look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) that may help you

Comment: Maybe `for (int i = input.length() - 1; i < input.length() ; i--)` -> `for (int i = input.length() - 1; i  >= 0 ; i--)`

Comment: @Yastanub -- don't fixate on any particular character encoding (e.g., ASCII, despite it's common-ness). C++ has character classification functions such as `std::isdigit`, `std::isalpha`, and `std::isalnum`,

Comment: Or just use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) for reversing the string?

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the tip! Of course i haven't worked with much character encoding yet and always instintively assume ascii encoding.

Comment: @Yastanub -- understood. That's why I keep pointing out blatant ASCIIism. <g>

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! As a beginner, ergh... I still don't understand some answers you gave to me, but still I appreciate your help! Thank you very much, didn't expect people here would be that so helpful ehehe.

Comment: "... numbers and/or letters as input from user, otherwise the program must be terminated" - I see no code to implement this requirement.   Perhaps by 'numbers' you mean digits and thus limit numbers to integers, i.e. no floats, doubles, etc.  But what do you mean by 'letters'?  commas? punctuation? parenthesis? tabs or other white space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way you can achieve what you want is checking every character. As @Pete Becker pointed out, you may use [isalnum](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalnum/) to check if the character is a number or a letter character:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
  std::string s = "Hello W>orld";

  for (auto c : s) {
    if (!isalnum(c)) {
      std::cout << "Found : '" << c << "'" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Found : ' '
Found : '>'
```

Comment: Just for completeness, `isalnum` returns true when its argument is a letter or a number.

Answer (score 2):

As @Someprogrammerdude mentioned in the comments, using *[std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)* and an appropriate binary predicate(lambda function), you can do it easily as follows.

Secondly, for checking the string `input` to its reverse string, just create a temporary string using [the reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) of `std::string` and check it. That way, you do not need to have another variable.

Hope the comments will help you to understand more options. 
<kbd>[SEE LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HosVOPufmSCClQBy)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> // std::isdigit and std::isalpha and std::isalnum
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::all_of

int main()
{
    std::string input; std::cin >> input;

    const auto check = [](const char eachCar)->bool{ return std::isalnum(eachCar); };
    /* change return statement of lambda to
        std::isdigit(eachCar)  ---> for only digits
        std::isalpha(eachCar)  ---> for only letters
    */
    if(std::all_of(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), check))
    {
        if(input == std::string(input.crbegin(), input.crend()))
            std::cout << "It is a palindrome!";
        else  std::cout << "No, it is not a palindrome!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**:

```
123kk321
```

**Output**:

```
It is a palindrome!
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume the input has no space, you can do like this:

```
char c; string s; bool chk = true;
while (cin >> c) 
{
    if (('0' <= c && c <= '9') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')) 
        s.push_back(c);
    else chk = false;
}
if (chk == true) cout << "Valid string";
else cout << "Invalid string";
```

The above code will terminate when there is no character left in the input.